# List of network connected drives with their connections paths

Tags: python

I have mapped network drive as disc "Z".
Let's say it's "\tefet12332\ImportantFolder".

The question is, how can I get this network drive path when I have got variable like:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path(r'Z:\Somefolder")
```

I want to do some "magic" with this variable and get "\tefet12332\ImportantFolder".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [`Path.resolve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve)

```
path = Path(r'Z:\Somefolder').resolve()
```

Otherwise you could use [`win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32wnet__WNetGetUniversalName_meth.html)

```
import win32wnet
path = win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName(r'Z:\Somefolder', 1)
```